# Clear followers from previous user search Github API

Tags: javascript, github-api

I'm trying to build a simple tool that will return a Github profile when you search someone's username. Everything seems to be working, except when I search for a different user, the list of followers from the **previous** user search don't clear.

For example, a user who has seven followers will suddenly have dozens of follower avatars displaying.

Can anyone tell me how to display the correct number of followers unique to each user when fetching different Github profiles?

```js
var response = null;
var followers = null;

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(r) {
  getUser(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
});

function getUser(name) {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + name)
    .then(function(r) {
        console.log(r.status);
        return r.json();
    })
    .then(function(j) {
        response = j;
        assignValues();
        getFollowers(j.followers_url);
    });
}

function assignValues() {
    document.getElementById('loader').style = 'display: none';

    document.getElementById('avatar').src = response.avatar_url;
    document.getElementById('name').innerText = response.name;
    document.getElementById('username').innerText = response.login;
    document.getElementById('location').innerText = response.location;
    document.getElementById('bio').innerText = response.bio;
    document.getElementById('count').innerText = 'Followers: ' + response.followers;
}

function getFollowers(url) {
    fetch(url)
    .then(function(r) {
        return r.json();
    })
    .then(function(f) {
        followers = f;
        listFollowers();
    });
}

function listFollowers() {
    followers.forEach(function(f) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = '<a href="' + f.html_url + '">'+ '<img src="' + f.avatar_url + '" alt="' + f.login + '"/>'+ '</a>';
        document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear that `#list` element in `listFollowers` function before starting appending new followers to it. For example:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
list.innerHTML = '';
followers.forEach(function(f) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = '<a href="' + f.html_url + '">'+ '<img src="' + f.avatar_url + '" alt="' + f.login + '"/>'+ '</a>';
    list.appendChild(li);
});
```

Three sidenotes here:

- why do you use global variables `response` and `followers` in your rendering functions when you can pass those as arguments?
- as you rerender a 'user profile' first, then wait for avatars' fetch, it's still possible for a user to see the followers of user X when looking for user Y. It's better to clear that section (and show some visual cue for loading data) immediately after the user is switched.
- as order of `fetch` responses is not guaranteed, there's a potential race condition here: if user clicks on that button twice (with different inputs), the earlier input might get back later - and overwrite the former. You need to guard against this, either by storing the latest input value and checking the response, or by some other means.

You can test those by artificially throttling the network speed. And believe me, in real world most of your user will have all sorts of problems with that.

Comment: thank you so much for the feedback! When you say storing the latest input do you mean by using sessionStorage?

Comment: No, just application variables.